# fetching data from mysql not working mobile only desktop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

Ihave a site on this site i have a responsive table for soccer tips.
So i can already connect to database to fetch date and it shows me on desktop.so it works on Desktop but on mobile i can not see anything.
I put the html and the css code down. so i am a beginner so please help me.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #FFED86;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
table * {
  position: relative;
}
table td, table th {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
table thead tr {
  height: 60px;
  background: #FFED86;
  font-size: 16px;
}
table tbody tr {
  height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
table tbody tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
table td, table th {
  text-align: left;
}
table td.l, table th.l {
  text-align: right;
}
table td.c, table th.c {
  text-align: center;
}
table td.r, table th.r {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) {
  table {
    display: block;
  }
  table > *, table tr, table td, table th {
    display: block;
  }
  table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table tbody tr {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td {
    padding-left: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
  table tbody tr td:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 40%;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "HOME";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(2):before {
    content: "AWAY";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "TIP";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "ODD";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "DATE";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(6):before {
    content: "TIME";
  }
}
body {
  background: #50040d;
  font: 400 14px 'Calibri','Arial';
  padding: 20px;
}

blockquote {
  color: #ffed86;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");
 
//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
$result = $dbConn->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Best Soccer Tips</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>
<blockquote> <strong>Best Soccer Tips</strong> </blockquote>

<body>

      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>HOME</th>
          <th>AWAY</th>
          <th>TIP</th>
          <th>ODD</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>TIME</th>
        </tr>
    <?php     
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['home']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['away']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['tip']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['odd']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['time']."</td>";    
               
    }
    ?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

       
      
    <table/>
      
    <blockquote> <strong>Best Soccer Tips</strong> </blockquote>
        <blockquote> <strong>Good Luck</strong> </blockquote>
  
  
</body>
```

Comment: try using `@media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) {` proper media queries

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) {
  table {
 display: block;

Comment: already there but no effect.if i make the browser smaller like under 600 px not showing me my table above 600 everything work same on mobile with dektop view it shows.but mobile only the blockquotes but not the table

Comment: here are pictures how it show dektop view and mobile view

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B79VYBNlaSb7a2Q0c09rSDROZ2M

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B79VYBNlaSb7amVKN2FHSVQyUmc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your `<table>`, `<thead>` and use `<tbody>` where you get rows. and try below example

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 1;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #FFED86;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
table * {
  position: relative;
}
table td, table th {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
table thead tr {
  height: 60px;
  background: #FFED86;
  font-size: 16px;
}
table tbody tr {
  height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
table tbody tr:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
table td, table th {
  text-align: left;
}
table td.l, table th.l {
  text-align: right;
}
table td.c, table th.c {
  text-align: center;
}
table td.r, table th.r {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) {
  table {
    display: block;
  }
  table > *, table tr, table td, table th {
    display: block;
  }
  table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table tbody tr {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td {
    padding-left: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
  table tbody tr td:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td:before {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 40%;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0;
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "HOME";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(2):before {
    content: "AWAY";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "TIP";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "ODD";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "DATE";
  }
  table tbody tr td:nth-child(6):before {
    content: "TIME";
  }
}
body {
  background: #50040d;
  font: 400 14px 'Calibri','Arial';
  padding: 20px;
}

blockquote {
  color: #ffed86;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<blockquote> <strong>Best Soccer Tips</strong> </blockquote>

<body>

      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>HOME</th>
          <th>AWAY</th>
          <th>TIP</th>
          <th>ODD</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>TIME</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>HOME</th>
          <th>AWAY</th>
          <th>TIP</th>
          <th>ODD</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>TIME</th>
        </tr>        <tr>
          <th>HOME</th>
          <th>AWAY</th>
          <th>TIP</th>
          <th>ODD</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>TIME</th>
        </tr>        <tr>
          <th>HOME</th>
          <th>AWAY</th>
          <th>TIP</th>
          <th>ODD</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>TIME</th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
      
    <blockquote> <strong>Best Soccer Tips</strong> </blockquote>
        <blockquote> <strong>Good Luck</strong> </blockquote>
```

Comment: i only closed  </thead> and works. thanks you are the best Pankaj

Comment: Please vote for correct answer and accept it

Comment: please explain me how i vote

Comment: Click on UP arraw and right sign on my answer

Comment: pankaj i thing i can not vote.    "But for voting you requires atleast 15 reputation, see this privileges page"  is that right?

Comment: yes, If you do not have atleast 15 votes you can not vote, but you can accept the answer. Which is below `Correct Icon` below Downvote of my Answer

Comment: if i have the right to vote i will vote you pankaj.thanks so much

Comment: i clicked on icon with start is that right?

Comment: already do it. thanks